# C++ not reading txt file for some reason

Tags: c++

I am new here and I was trying to run this program for my assignment. When I run it in my computer, it doesnt recognise the txt file.

Heres the code,
I have the txt file in the same folder as this program and I also have no other txt file with same name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct process {
    int pid;
    int arrival_time;
    int burst_time;
    int start_time;
    int completion_time;
    int turnaround_time;
    int waiting_time;
    int response_time;
};

int main() {
    
    char retry;
do{
    int n;
    struct process p[100];
    float avg_turnaround_time;
    float avg_waiting_time;
    float avg_response_time;
    float cpu_utilisation;
    int total_turnaround_time = 0;
    int total_waiting_time = 0;
    int total_response_time = 0;
    int total_idle_time = 0;
    float throughput;
    int is_completed[100];
    
    ifstream checker;
    int i, nop, j, k;
    
    memset(is_completed,0,sizeof(is_completed));

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    checker.open("mp1.txt");
    cout<<" Checking number of processes from file " << endl;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++)
    {
        checker >> n;
    }
    
    cout <<"Number of Processes = " << n << endl;
    
    cout<<"Arrival Time:"<<endl;
    for (j = 0 ; j < n ;j ++)
    {
        checker >> p[j].arrival_time;
        cout<<"P"<<j+1<<": "<<p[j].arrival_time<<endl;
        p[j].pid = j+1;
    }
    
    cout<<"Burst Time:"<<endl;
    for (k = 0 ; k < n ;k ++)
    {
        checker >> p[k].burst_time;
        cout<<"P"<<k+1<<": "<<p[k].burst_time<<endl;
    }
    

    int current_time = 0;
    int completed = 0;
    int prev = 0;

    while(completed != n) {
        int idx = -1;
        int mn = 10000000;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(p[i].arrival_time <= current_time && is_completed[i] == 0) {
                if(p[i].burst_time < mn) {
                    mn = p[i].burst_time;
                    idx = i;
                }
                if(p[i].burst_time == mn) {
                    if(p[i].arrival_time < p[idx].arrival_time) {
                        mn = p[i].burst_time;
                        idx = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(idx != -1) {
            p[idx].start_time = current_time;
            p[idx].completion_time = p[idx].start_time + p[idx].burst_time;
            p[idx].turnaround_time = p[idx].completion_time - p[idx].arrival_time;
            p[idx].waiting_time = p[idx].turnaround_time - p[idx].burst_time;
            p[idx].response_time = p[idx].start_time - p[idx].arrival_time;
            
            total_turnaround_time += p[idx].turnaround_time;
            total_waiting_time += p[idx].waiting_time;
            total_response_time += p[idx].response_time;
            total_idle_time += p[idx].start_time - prev;

            is_completed[idx] = 1;
            completed++;
            current_time = p[idx].completion_time;
            prev = current_time;
        }
        else {
            current_time++;
        }
        
    }

    int min_arrival_time = 10000000;
    int max_completion_time = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        min_arrival_time = min(min_arrival_time,p[i].arrival_time);
        max_completion_time = max(max_completion_time,p[i].completion_time);
    }

    avg_turnaround_time = (float) total_turnaround_time / n;
    avg_waiting_time = (float) total_waiting_time / n;
    avg_response_time = (float) total_response_time / n;
    cpu_utilisation = ((max_completion_time - total_idle_time) / (float) max_completion_time )*100;
    throughput = float(n) / (max_completion_time - min_arrival_time);

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"#P\t\t"<<"TAT\t\t"<<"WT\t"<<"\n"<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout<<p[i].pid<<"\t\t"<<p[i].turnaround_time<<"\t\t"<<p[i].waiting_time<<"\t\t"<<"\n"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Total"<<"\t\t"<<total_turnaround_time<<"\t\t"<<total_waiting_time<<endl;
    cout<<"Average"<<"\t\t"<<avg_turnaround_time<<"\t\t"<<avg_waiting_time<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Do you want to run again [y/n]: ";
    cin>>retry;
}while(retry != 'n');

}
```

the values in the txt file are,

**5**

**0 3 6 9 12**

**30 25 15 10 20**

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: By the way, what use is a loop that iterates only once? Like `for (i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++)`?

Comment: And you really need some error checking. You don't check that you actually opened the file successfully.

Comment: what does `checker.is_open()` return? If false then narrow down the problem by using the full path to the filename.

Comment: When you say "I have the txt file in the same folder as this program" you mean as the compiled output of the program (.exe) not the source file (.cpp) right?

Comment: The [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) might not be what you expect.